# Flutter Http getting a response but passing null to then when the method is call

Tags: flutter, dart

I actually get the response from my API, using this method.

```
static Future<String> saveData(String url, Vehicle vehicle) async {
dio.Dio d = dio.Dio();


Map<String, dynamic> headers = {};
headers['Cookie'] = "JSESSIONID=" + "fff";// SessionUtils().getSession().toString();
dio.Options options = dio.Options(
    headers: headers,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    responseType: dio.ResponseType.json,
);

final dio.Response response = await d.post(url, options: options, data: jsonEncode(vehicle));

print(response.data);
dynamic item;
String result = "";
if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
  item = response.data; //json.decode(response.data);

  print("****************");
  print(item);
  print("****************");
  print(item["id"]);

  if(item["success"]){
    result = item["id"]; // **result is correct here** 
    print("OK");
  }
  print(item["success"]); // Data is printed out correctly
}
print(result);

return result;
```

}

But when I call this method using the code below I cannot get the returned data in the then.

```
VehicleHttpService.saveData(Constant.POST_VEHICLE_URL, widget.vehicle).then((value){
          }).then((String? value){
            print("#########");
            print(value); //**I get null here. why**
            print("#########");
          }).whenComplete((){
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          });
```

I was expecting the result returned by saveData. Please help me check what is wrong with my code.

Comment: But I see two `then()`. Your print is in the second `then()` method, shouldn't it be just a then? Remove the first `then()` and see what happens.

Comment: may be because your function return String but in then method it accepts nullable String , so try to make the return type String? or try to make the accepted String ,

Answer (score 0):

Let's check your executing code by parts:

```
VehicleHttpService.saveData(Constant.POST_VEHICLE_URL, widget.vehicle).then((value){
      }).then((String? value){
        print("#########");
        print(value); //**I get null here. why**
        print("#########");
      }).whenComplete((){
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      });
```

The **first step** is executing the API request and return a response

```
VehicleHttpService.saveData(Constant.POST_VEHICLE_URL, widget.vehicle)
```

The **second step** is receives the response, converts it in `null` and return to the `Future` chain

```
then((value){})
```

The **third step** always will receive the `null`

```
then((String? value){
        print("#########");
        print(value); //**I get null here. why**
        print("#########");
      }).whenComplete((){
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      })
```

Remove `then` in the middle and you will receive the response and can able to handle it